# How to enter data in existing Excel sheet and save

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to enter data in Excel sheet. After enter data I am trying to save Excel file using vbscript. But it's asking "file already exists do you want to replace".

How I can write code for it, should not ask that pop up it should save Excel sheet.

```
Set PinXL = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set PinWB = PinXL.Workbook`enter code here`s.Open("C:\Maspects\Trial.xls")                          
Set PinWS = PinWB.Worksheets("LoginPins")
pinws.cells(2,8)=8

pinwb.save // In this statement I am facing issue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try shutting off the excel application's `DisplayAlerts` property while saving:

```
PinXL.DisplayAlerts = False
pinwb.save
PinXL.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Now i am facing a problem Not able to access red file,if i open excell its showing red only how i can fix that problem

Comment: That means the file is probably already open and you are trying to reopen it here in the code.